# D3 annotations in wrong place along x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am using the wonderful plugin d3 annotations and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why are my annotation being placed in the wrong area along my x axis. I'm using a time scale to determine the range of my axis and I'm using the same for the annotations but somehow it isn't working. I've followed the same process found in the documentation (https://bl.ocks.org/susielu/23dc3082669ee026c552b85081d90976).

[image: annotations in the wrong place]

X scale:

```
 const xScale = d3
.scaleTime()
.domain(d3.extent(data, xAccessor))
.range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
.nice();
```

Annotations:

```
    const annotations = [
    {
      note: {
        label: 'National emergency is declared',
        align: 'center',
        wrap: 100,
      },
      subject: {
        y1: dimensions.margin.top + 40,
        y2: dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.bottom,
      },
      y: dimensions.height - dimensions.boundedHeight,
      data: { x: dateParser('2020-3-13') }, // position the x based on an x scale
    },
    {
      note: {
        label: `Florida's stay at home rule is declared`,
        align: 'right',
        wrap: 120,
      },
      subject: {
        y1: dimensions.margin.top + 40,
        y2: dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.bottom,
      },
      y: dimensions.height - (dimensions.boundedHeight - 10),
      data: { x: dateParser('2020-4-1') },
    },
  ];

  const type = d3.annotationCustomType(d3.annotationXYThreshold, {
    note: {
      lineType: 'none',
      orientation: 'top',
    },
  });

  // 12 - render the annotations
  const makeAnnotations = d3
    .annotation()
    .type(type)
    .accessors({
      x(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
      },
      y(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
      },
    })
    .annotations(annotations)
    .textWrap(30);

  wrapper
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'annotation-group')
    .call(makeAnnotations);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your dataviz, both annotations are off (to the left) by the same amount. The code you posted is not enough to see what's happening, but since you have this as the scale's range...

```
.range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
```

... I bet you are appending the axis and the other elements to a groups which is translated by the left-marging amount you set while appending the annotations to another group (inside `wrapper`, whatever that is), which is not translated by the same amount.

That being said, the solutions are:

1. Append the annotations to the same (translated) group you put the axis in;
2. Set the scale's range with the margin...

   ```
   .range([leftMargin, dimensions.boundedWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin])
   ```

   ... and then append everything to a non-translated group.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo ! You were right ! I was appending the annotations in a different place ! I've been working on this project for so many hours that I missed that simple step !